# How do I get DISTINCT column A, with SUM of column B?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm relatively new to coding and have tried searching for a solution, but am not entirely sure how to phrase my question. What would be simplest way to achieve the result I need, as detailed in the example that follows? I'm using MSSQL.

```
SELECT Unit, Quantity FROM SomeTable WHERE Parameter1 = 'x'
```

Gives me the result:

```
Unit | Quantity
---------------
a    | 10
b    | 10
c    | 10
a    | 10
```

This is the result I need:

```
Unit | Quantity
---------------
a    | 20
b    | 10
c    | 10
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a [`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) so do the trick for you.

```
SELECT Unit, Sum(Quantity)
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Parameter1 = 'x'
GROUP BY Unit
```

Comment: Thanks a mil! I'm really battling to Google solutions to problems, when I'm not 100% familiar with the correct terminology yet -_-

Answer (score 0):

When you select rows, SQL looks at each row individually, unless an "aggregate function" is used. Aggregates are, for instance, sum(), count(), avg(), min(), and max(). (And many more, in many vendor SQL packages.) This is why you end up with two "copies" of A in your result set; SQL displays each of them individually, since they are two distinct rows. Instead, you can use these functions to find the aggregate value.

When SQL looks at an aggregate, it needs to know which rows to examine. By default, if all quantities used in the query are aggregates, it looks at all rows. For instance, in your example, `Select Sum(Quantity) from SomeTable where Parameter1='x'` would return `40`, the sum of all values in the column that match the criteria.

You are looking for an aggregate of a group of rows, in this case, items that have the same `Unit` value. To tell SQL this, you need to tell it how to define the group, using a `Group By` Clause. As Bluefeet's answer pointed out, this can be done by writing:

```
SELECT Unit, Sum(Quantity)
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Parameter1 = 'x'
GROUP BY Unit
```

As a general pointer, the query will fail if you want to find an agggregate and a value without grouping. For instance, if instead of restricting the query to Parameter1='x', you wanted to look at the parameter associated with the row, you might be tempted to just add this into the select list, `SELECT Unit, Sum(Quantity), Parameter1...` and run the query. This won't work, because SQL does not know what row to look at to find the parameter.

You can group by multiple columns, if this is needed. If a more complex group is needed, many more tricks can be used.  For instance, you can group over a case statement, or over a function of a row, to find the sum of all even numbered items, for instance, or the average order size for orders over 100 units.